# Use regex to remove a decimal point

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, awk

I have about 5,000 files with an error I need to correct. Each file has a section that looks something like:

```
<rating system="nl-movies">16.0</rating>
<rating system="ro-movies">8.0</rating>

<rating *something*>A.0</rating>
```

I need to remove the `.0` from each of these, so that the text instead looks like:

```
<rating system="nl-movies">16</rating>
<rating system="ro-movies">8</rating>

<rating *something*>A</rating>
```

In other words, I need to replace `.0</rating>` with `</rating>`. How would I do this in unix and make the changes recursive down the folder structure?

Thanks for all the help: this is what ended up working:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i 's/\.0<\/rating>/<\/rating>/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do this for you

```
find /some/path -type f | xargs sed -i 's/\.0\(<\/rating>\)/\1/g'
```

Replace `/some/path` with the path of the base directory you would like to start the replacements, you might also want to add something like `-name *.xml` to the `find` command if all files have the same suffix.

Answer (score 1):

#### Replace All Trailing Decimals

If you want to replace all trailing decimals, not just those that end in `.0`, then you can use this expression.

```
sed 's/\.[[:digit:]]\+</</' /tmp/foo
```

#### Replace Just .0

If you want remove just .0, and not other decimals, then you can be more specific. For example:

```
sed 's/\.0</</' /tmp/foo
```

In this case, it will remove the decimal from 8.0, but not 8.1. You may need to do some additional tweaking if you want to handle cases like "B.6" though.

Comment: an important hint might be to use `sed -i` to make the changes in place

Comment: It is not just a trailing decimal, but `.0</rating>` --> `</rating>`. There may be other decimals in the file that cannot be overwritten.

Comment: THen change [[:digit:]] to simple 0

Comment: @David542 The angle bracket anchors the expression, and works fine on the provided corpus. If you have a use case where this doesn't work, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Safe solution for a single file would be:

```
sed -ri 's/(<rating[^>]*>[^.<]+)\.0(<\/rating>)/\1\2/g' file.txt
```

and for multiple files in directory `/path`:

```
find /path -name *.txt | xargs sed -ri 's/(<rating[^>]*>[^.<]+)\.0(<\/rating>)/\1\2/g'
```